# How can I change from onclick button to eventListener? (forEach included)

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, addeventlistener

I have trouble switching from onclick to event listener. [Picture link here: I want to change this portfolio buttons to not be onclick][1]I tryed everything i know that it needs to go trough forEach because it's node list, so i did that and it's not working. Than i write my code back to normal with onclick and it's working. But i need event listener instead.

```js
let menu = document.querySelector('.header ul');
let btn = document.querySelector('.button');

btn.addEventListener("click" , () => {
    if(btn.innerText === 'MENU') {       //uzeli smo btn i premenili mu ime u menu innerTextom 
        menu.style.display = 'block'; //zatim pisemo da ako je btn jednako menu da bude display block
        btn.innerText ='CLOSE'; 
           // i kad klikenmo na menu da se ispise close, da bi zatvorili
   

    }else{
        menu.style.display = 'none';      
        btn.innerText ='MENU';
        }
});

//SLIDER galerija 

let rightBtn = document.querySelector('#right-btn');      //selektujemo dugmice za slider levo i desno
let leftBtn = document.querySelector('#left-btn');
let pictures = document.querySelectorAll('.slider-images img')

let imgNum = 0;  //krecemo sa pozicije nula

rightBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    displayNone()        //ovde pozivamo funkciju koju smo dole pre toga napravili za slider
    imgNum++;            // stavljamo ++ da bi se dodala svaki put po jedna slika

    if (imgNum === pictures.length){   //ako smo dobili da je broj slika 3, merimo lengtom
                                       //onda ga vrati opet na nulu
        imgNum = 0;
    }
    pictures[imgNum].style.display = 'block';  // koja se iz none display u block
})
leftBtn.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
    displayNone();                 
    imgNum--;                      
    if (imgNum === -1){                    //-1 uvek vrati za pojednu nazad ne idi dalje od 2 
        imgNum = pictures.length - 1;
    }

    pictures[imgNum].style.display = 'block';
   });

   //zatim ovde pravimo fuknciju
   //ova funkcija krije slike
   const displayNone = () => {
       pictures.forEach((img) => {
        img.style.display ='none';
       })

   }

   // ----------PORTFOLIO---------------

//Uzimamo dugme button funkcijom i stavljamo argument zato sto u htmlu imamo THIS

const portfolioSort = (button) => {
    let category = button.getAttribute('data-category');   // uzimamo atribut buttona i dispaly text
    let portfolioItems = document.querySelectorAll('.portfolio-single-item');
    
    portfolioItems.forEach((item) => {
        item.style.display ='none';
    });

   if(category === 'sve') {
       portfolioItems.forEach((item) => {
            item.style.display = 'block'
       })

       portfolioItems.forEach((item) => {
           if(item.getAttribute('data-category').includes(category)) {
               item.style.display = 'block';
           }
       })
   } 

    };
          
     
     
  
     
    



//-------MODAL BUTTON--------

    let openmodal = document.querySelector('.modal-section button')
    let modalWindow = document.querySelector('.popup-modal');
    let overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
    openmodal.addEventListener("click" ,()=>{
    modalWindow.style.display = 'block';
    overlay.style.display = 'block';
    });


// zatvaramo modal 
    let closemodal = document.querySelector('.popup-modal button')
     modalWindow = document.querySelector('.popup-modal');
     overlay = document.querySelector('.overlay');
    closemodal.addEventListener("click", ()=>{ 
    modalWindow.style.display = 'none';
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Meni Slider Portfolio</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>


    <div class="header">
        <img src="img/logo.png">

        <button class="button">MENU</button>

        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Početna</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">O nama</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Usluge</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Galerija</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <h2>Galerija</h2>

    <div class="slider-wrapper">
        <button id="left-btn"><i class="arrow"></i></button>
        <div class="slider-images">
            <img src="img/slide1.jpg">
            <img src="img/slide2.jpg">
            <img src="img/slide3.jpg">
        </div>
        <button id="right-btn"><i class="arrow"></i></button>
    </div>

    <h2>Portfolio</h2>

    <div class="portfolio-wrapper">
        <div class="portfolio-categories">
            <button data-category='sve' onclick="portfolioSort(this)">Sve</button>
            <button data-category='restorani' onclick="portfolioSort(this)" class="brown">Restorani</button>
            <button data-category='hoteli' onclick="portfolioSort(this)" class="blue">Hoteli</button>
            <button data-category='korporacije' onclick="portfolioSort(this)" class="green">Korporacije</button>
            <button data-category='ostalo' onclick="portfolioSort(this)" class="rose">Ostalo</button>
            <button data-category='bazeni' onclick="portfolioSort(this)" class="purple">Bazeni</button>
            <button data-category='skijaske-staze'onclick="portfolioSort(this)"class="yellow">Skijaske Staze</button>
        </div>

        <div class="portfolio-items">
            <div class="portfolio-single-item blue" data-category='hoteli'>
                <h3>Hotel 1</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-single-item rose" data-category='ostalo'>
                <h3>Startup</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-single-item blue" data-category='hoteli, restorani'>
                <h3>Hotel & Restoran</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-single-item green" data-category='korporacije'>
                <h3>Korporacija 1</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-single-item brown" data-category='restorani'>
                <h3>Restoran 1</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-single-item rose" data-category='ostalo'>
                <h3>XYZ Orgranizacija</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-single-item blue" data-category='hoteli'>
                <h3>Hotel 2</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-single-item green" data-category='korporacije'>
                <h3>Korporacija 2</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-single-item brown" data-category='restorani'>
                <h3>Restoran 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-single-item purple" data-category='bazeni'>
                <h3>Bazen 1</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-single-item purple" data-category='bazeni'>
                <h3>Bazen 2</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-single-item yellow" data-category='skijaske-staze'>
                <h3>Staza 1 </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-single-item yellow" data-category='skijaske-staze'>
                <h3>Staza 2 </h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-section">
        <button >Modal Button</button>
    </div>


    <div class="popup-modal">
        <button id="closeModal">X</button>

        <h4>Modal Title</h4>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="modal-section">
        <button onclick="openModal()">Modal Button</button>
    </div>


    <div class="popup-modal">
        <button id="closeModal" onclick="closeModal()">X</button>

        <h4>Modal Title</h4>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </div>

    <div class="overlay"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [David Walsh :: How JavaScript Event Delegation Works](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) ... as for the current button markup ... `document.querySelector('.portfolio-categories').addEventListener('click', evt => portfolioSort(evt.target))` ... in case of buttons with additionally nested elements ... `document.querySelector('.portfolio-categories').addEventListener('click', evt => portfolioSort(evt.target.closest('button')))`

Answer (score -1):

give them all a class with the same name, then select them with [document.querySelectAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and add the EventListener to it, like:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.myClassName')].forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', portfolioSort));
```